# Como recuperar a URL da página anterior ASP

Tags: javascript, asp

Galera, boa tarde.

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma dica para eu pegar a URL da página anterior no seguinte cenário:

- Uma página MVC tem um link para uma página ASP
- Clicar no link
- Abre a página ASP
  ** Neste momento, como faço para guardar a URL da página MVC?

Obg!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via JavaScript você pode usar:

```
var paginaAnterior = document.referrer;
```

Se optar capturar pelo ASP Clássico

```
paginaAnterior = Request.ServerVariables ("HTTP_REFERER")
```